# Creating a public document directory for a normal user

Tags: apache-httpd, webserver, multiuser

We usually see personal web pages like `http://example.com/~someone/`, in this case, "someone" is a user of "example.com".

How to enable this by default, so whenever we add a new user "foo", then `http://example.com/~foo/` is created automatically? Is the tilde in "~someone" optional, customizable?

**Software environment:**

Webserver: Apache or Yaws (Erlang based webserver)

Comment: What webserver? Apache?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I am actually testing Yaws, yet, solutions using Apache are also appreciated since Apache is currently more widely used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Yaws, you're looking for the [`tilde_expand`](http://yaws.hyber.org/yman.yaws?page=yaws.conf) configuration option.

There is nothing *magical* about the `~` character, but it is so common that I wouldn't recommend trying to circumvent it. If you want to forgo it completely, then give users the ability to edit content in `/var/www/htdocs/<username>/` themselves.

Answer (score 5):

For Apache, see if http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_userdir.html#userdir and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/public_html.html helps.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

and

```
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
```

in your httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Update this line in httpd configuration

`UserDir .www`

and ask users to create ~/.www directory themselves in their home directory if they want to share something over web. Ask them to share their files over http(scrutiny on themselves).

In the load module section, add this line

`LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so`

In order to give each user their own cgi-bin directory, you can use a  directive to make a particular subdirectory of a user's home directory cgi-enabled.

```
<Directory /home/*/.www/cgi-bin/>
Options ExecCGI
SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>
```

Restart or HUP httpd service.